# Explain weird c++ compilation and syntax

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++

Can someone explain why this block of code is valid syntax? Why does it compile?

```
void foo(){}
enum class X { X1, X2 };

int main()
{
    auto s = X::X1;
    foo(),s = X::X2;
    return 0;
}
```

Using ***Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)***.

**Edit:**

The line in question as Some Programmer Dude mentioned 
     `foo(),s = X::X2;`

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: Is there something in particular that makes you worry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean

```
foo(),s = X::X2;
```

That's actually equal to

```
(foo()),(s = X::X2);
```

That is, it's the expression `foo()` which calls the `foo` function, and the expression `s = X::X2`, divided by the [*comma operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).